# Gauge field canonical momentum (curved spaces)

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, gauge-theory, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

**The problem**

I am working on gauge fields on curved manifolds and struggle to find a good definition of the canonical momentum and respective hamiltonian/energy momentum tensor.

Without the gauge fixing term we do not encounter problems and I know that it can be proven that:

$$
T^{\mu\nu}_\mathcal{C} = -2\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial F_{\mu\rho}}F^{\nu\rho}-g^{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}
$$
is gauge invariant and coincides with the energy momentum tensor in general relativity $T^{\mu\nu}_\mathcal{G} = \frac{-2}{\sqrt{g}}\frac{\partial\sqrt{g}\mathcal{L}}{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}$ such that it is the true energy momentum tensor.

It is also covariantly constant and allows us to construct a conserved currect $\mathcal{J^\nu}_\mathcal{C} = k_\mu T^{\mu\nu}_\mathcal{C}$ for every killing vector $k_\mu$.

However when we add a gauge fixing term to the "normal" QED lagrangian such that it becomes:

$$\mathcal{L}_{FP} = \frac{-1}{2}\nabla_\mu A_\nu \nabla^\mu A^\nu.$$

We can no longer calculate $T^{\mu\nu}_\mathcal{C}$!

**My suggested solution**

I tried to solve this via the introduction of

$$T^{\mu\nu}_{FP} = \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \nabla_\mu A_\rho}\nabla^\nu A_\rho.$$

It is easy to show that $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}_{FP}=0$ but we can no longer define a conserved current $\mathcal{J}^\nu$ (or at least not that I see)

So how do I define the energy of this gauge fixed QED lagrangian if there is no conserved current from which we can pick the 0-th component?

**Wrong solutions**

- We cannot take $T^{00}_{FP} = E$ as this is not even a scalar
- We could suggest the conserved current $\mathcal{J}^\nu_{FP} = k_\mu T^{\mu\nu}_{FP}$ with $k_\mu$ a covariantly constant killing vector, but this gives unsatisfactory results in my case so I'd rather not do this...

**Final note**
Does anyone have any idea why this isn't documented very well. I would have expected this to be a very well known topic but after searching for solutions for several days this turns out to be untrue. Why?

Comment: I recall a paper showing that the energy term of the gauge fixing term is cancelled out by the energy term of the ghost term. Hopefully it will help!

Comment: @Slereah Do you mean that the longitudinal polarization is canceled by the timelike polarization ? 
Because this is indeed true, or it least it should be, but it does not tell us how to define the energy momentum tensor does it ?